# How to let AUCTeX launch automatically pythontex.py script

Tags: compiling, emacs, auctex, pythontex

I need to use the `pythontex` package that I find very useful if someone has to do some calculation before inserting the  results in LaTeX. So Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{pythontex}
  \begin{document}
    If we add five to eight we get \py{5+8}.
   \end{document}
```

I am used to typeset my LaTeX documents in Emacs with AUCTeX.  To compile the document I generally use the the keys `C-c C-a` which are bound to the AUCTeX command `TeX-command-run-all` described in the AUCTeX manual as:

> Compile the current document until an error occurs or
>        it is finished.  If compilation finishes successfully, run the
>        viewer at the end.

But with the example provided above I get this result:
[image]

As we can see the result of the python calculation has been replaced by ?? . This is because as described in the pythontex package manual :

> Compiling a document with pythontex involves three steps:
>      1) running a LaTeX-compatible tex engine;
>      2) running pythontex.py script;
>      3) and finally running the TeX engine again.

The second step is not automatically performed by the `TeX-command-run-all` command so I need to leave momentarily Emacs, open a terminal (I am on GNU/Linux) and type `pythontex <myfile.tex>`, and return to Emacs to run again `TeX-command-run-all`. As we can easily imagine it is somewhat painful to do this seven times.

**The question**: How to configure AUCTeX in a way that when I call `TeX-command-run-all` the `pythontex.py` script is automatically launched so there is no need any more to use a terminal and execute the script manually?

Comment: I would configure AucTeX to add a command to run "latexmk", and then use a `.latexmkrc` file like this one: http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/pythontex-latexmkrc. See also the discussion at https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/132.

Comment: It might also be good to ask this at https://emacs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JohnPalmieri thank you for your reply. I dit  it [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52046/running-pytontex-script-in-auctex) but no answers until now.

Comment: What is the version of Emacs you're using (`C-h v emacs-version RET`)?

Comment: @ArashEsbati emacs-version "25.2.1"

Comment: Can you please restart Emacs, eval the following in `*scratch*`: `(with-eval-after-load "tex"
  (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
               '("PythonTeX" "pythontex %s" TeX-run-command nil (latex-mode)
                 :help "Run PythonTeX script")
               t))

(defun my/TeX-run-TeX-pythontex ()
  (TeX-command-sequence '("LaTeX" "PythonTeX" "LaTeX" "View")))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c p") #'my/TeX-run-TeX-pythontex)))`, open you .tex file and hit `C-c p`? Thanks.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Thank you for your interest. Following your instructions I get a message something like `C-c p` is not defined. But putting your code in my `.emacs` , restarting then emacs and hitting `C-c p` I get the following `Wrong type argument: commandp, my/TeX-run-TeX-pythontex`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, please try this piece of code in your `.emacs`: `(defun my/TeX-run-TeX-pythontex ()
  (interactive)
  (TeX-command-sequence '("LaTeX" "PythonTeX" "LaTeX" "View")))`

Comment: @ArashEsbati So I need just to insert `(interactive)`  in the previous code? Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, correct, it was missing.

Comment: @ArashEsbati How to automatically save tex file before compiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you don't hack on AUCTeX's commands but define your own one.  You can define a series of shell commands to run via `TeX-command-sequence`.

> (TeX-command-sequence COMMAND &optional RESET FILE-FN)
>
> Run a sequence of TeX commands defined by COMMAND.
>
> The COMMAND argument may be
>
> - `nil`: no command will be run in this case
> - a string with a command from `TeX-command-list`
> - a non-nil list of strings, which are commands from
>     `TeX-command-list`; the car of the list is used as command to
>     be executed in the first run of `TeX-command-sequence`, the
>     cdr of the list will be passed to the function in the next
>     run, etc.
> - a function name, returning a string which is command from
>     `TeX-command-list`; it will be funcall’d (without arguments!)
>     and used again in the next run of `TeX-command-sequence`.
> - with any other value the function `TeX-command-default` is
>     used to determine the command to run, until a stopping
>     condition is met.
>
> [...] A non-nil value for the optional argument RESET means this is
>   the first run of the function and some variables need to be reset.

So the basic strategy is: Add an entry for `PythonTeX` to `TeX-command-list`, define a private function which saves your document and runs `TeX-command-sequence` appropriately, bind this private function to a key in LaTeX mode and then run it.

```el
(with-eval-after-load "tex"
  (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
               '("PythonTeX" "pythontex %s" TeX-run-command nil (latex-mode)
                 :help "Run PythonTeX script")
               t))

(defun my/TeX-run-TeX-pythontex ()
  "Save current master file, run LaTeX, PythonTeX and start the viewer."
  (interactive)
  (unless (featurep 'tex-buf)
    (require 'tex-buf))
  (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file))
  (TeX-command-sequence '("LaTeX" "PythonTeX" "LaTeX" "View") 
                        t))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c p") #'my/TeX-run-TeX-pythontex)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that [latexmk](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk?lang=en) is designed for this kind of situation. It's included in some TeX distributions, so you may have it already. Once it's configured properly, you should just have to run it once, and it will automatically detect whether Python needs to be run, run it, and then rerun LaTeX if needed. Anyway, once you have `latexmk`, in Emacs, run `M-x customize-group AUCTeX`. Then choose `TeX Command`, and within that menu, customize `TeX-command-list`: add a line

```
("latexmk" "latexmk %t" TeX-run-command nil t)
```

Now you should have an option to run `latexmk` on your LaTeX files, so you need to configure `latexmk` to check whether `pythontex` requires running Python. (I also add `(setq TeX-command-default "latexmk")` to an appropriate hook so this is evaluated whenever I edit a `.tex` file.) The author of `latexmk` has provided a [sample configuration file](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/pythontex-latexmkrc) for use with `pythontex`. You can also do an internet search for "latexmk pythontex". (I don't use pythontex, so I can't vouch for this. I use sagetex, and `latexmk` works beautifully with that, so I would expect it to work equally well with pythontex.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your good answer. I am sorry for the bounty. In my opinion in this situation the bounty should be equally shared by two answers but it is not possible and I had to make a choice. Thank you again!